Как выйти из пользователя Linux, не завершая его процессы?
Хочу написать программу, которая дистанционно управляет компьютером. Застрял на одном моменте: есть удобное сочетание клавиш Super+L, которое выходит из пользователя, но оставляет все процессы запущенными. Я не знаю, как реализовать такое при помощи команды.
Подскажите нужную команду

Вы случайно не путаете выход с блокировкой экрана?

tmux/screen.

В графическом интерфейсе
Команда универсальная для современных ОС
loginctl lock-session

Для гнома и убунту можно ещё так ( если по ssh подключен, то надо указать путь до дбас )
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver \
    /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock

или так
gnome-screensaver-command  --lock  --activate

